# Expecting statement?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have created a file that contains general functions. The goal of this file is include it inside the main file and use the functions available in it.

Anyway at the top of all, so `<?php` PhpStorm return:

> Expecting Stament

what does mean?

an example of the file structure:

```
<?php //here the problem


public function getTimeStamp()
{
    $originalTime = microTime(true);
    $micro = sprintf("%06d", ($originalTime - floor($originalTime)) * 1000000);
    $date = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s' . $micro, $originalTime));

    return $date->format($this->settings['dateFormat']);

} //and also here

 ...

?>
```

what I did wrong?

Comment: please show code on formating remove `'` and pust comment and show class name and over code. And stacktrace too.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your problem is that you have defined it as a `public` function when you are outside of a class.

Simply change

```
public function getTimeStamp()
```

to

```
function getTimeStamp()
```

Comment: So I can't set public function or protected function in a general functions file?

Comment: That is correct. Public, private and protected specify how accessible a method IN a class is. When you have a function outside of a class, it is not applicable.

Comment: also check all functions with pair *{* and *}*, if some of them is missed, thats why program will awaits your input, and that why  program printed that warning !

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you haven't declared a function within another function. That will cause this error as well. For example:

```
class bob {

   public function process(){

      // bunch of code here

       protected function hello() {
           //wrong spot!
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function getTimeStamp()
{
    $originalTime = microTime(true);
    $micro = sprintf("%06d", ($originalTime - floor($originalTime)) * 1000000);
    $date = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s.' . $micro, $originalTime));

    return $date->format($this->settings['dateFormat']);

} //and also here
```

you forgot dote '.' in new DateTime() you get not right string.